# UI slider drag on finsih in ngui

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, uislider, ngui

Is there any way available to detect [UI Slider](http://www.tasharen.com/forum/index.php?topic=6715.0) drag have finished. I found this [docs](http://tasharen.com/ngui/docs/class_u_i_slider.html) but it didn't have such kind of event.
I want to do some particular work on ui slider drag on finished i.e., require an event which fire.

Comment: Just FWIW Mohammad, there is almost no point using "NGUI" these days.  It was a great program but nowadays Unity has UI.  Unity's own UI is incredibly simpler to use than any of the old-days asset store solutions.  for eampe the slider is incredibly easy to use https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/ui/ui-slider

Comment: (if i'm not mistaken the NGUI fellow actually went over to Unity to build stuff for them, heh!)

Comment: it can be nice suggestion but not my answer